# How to change map array to comparable numbers?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

Project contains 7 cards , each card has own ID. I selected this ID .
I have data in JS file , this data has 7 objects with ID ,
I want compare card ID with data ID ,
IF THIS IDs WILL MATCH , THEN WILL PRINT IT .
console.log show me this

3 = card ID

(7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]  = data file shows me array

How to change this array , I could compare card ID ?

```
const cardbody = document.querySelectorAll('.card')

cardbody.forEach(function(btn) {
  console.log(btn)  // it shows me current card
  
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    
    const bt = e.currentTarget.dataset.id
    console.log(bt)  // 3 


  // data from JS file  this return arrays
   const dataid = cabins.map(function(item) {  
     return item.id
   })
   console.log(dataid)  //(7) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

   if(dataid === bt ) {
     console.log('red')
     }

  })
})
```

Comment: `dataid` is an array, `bt` is a single number. Maybe you want `if (dataid.includes(bt))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to know if the `bt` is in any of the `id` properties, use the `some()` method. You don't need to create an array first.

```
cardbody.forEach(function(btn) {
  console.log(btn) // it shows me current card

  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    const bt = e.currentTarget.dataset.id
    console.log(bt) // 3 

    if (cabins.some(item => item.id == bt)) {
      console.log('red')
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const id = 3;

// existance
if (arr.includes(id)) {
  console.log(`${id} exists`);
}

// findIndex
if (arr.indexOf(id) >= 0) {
  console.log(`${id} found at arr[${arr.indexOf(id)}]`);
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 